# JSONObject not response

Tags: android, json

How do I check if this text appears or not

`{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}`

url : http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=fddfgdfgdfgdfg&units=metric&appid=efb8013262db1b77b0431909b8b173e1

My try

```
public void btn_search(View view) {
        CheckInternet checkInternet = new CheckInternet(MainActivity.this);
        boolean ci = checkInternet.isconnecting();
        if(ci)
        {
            EditText ed_Search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Search);
            if(ed_Search.getText().length() > 0)
            {
                String urlOpenWeatherMap =  "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=fddfgdfgdfgdfg&units=metric&appid=efb8013262db1b77b0431909b8b173e1";
                progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                btn_search = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
                btn_search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlOpenWeatherMap, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    String x = response.getString("message");
                                    if(x.contains("404") || x.contains("city not found") )
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonobjectrequest);

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to solve the problem 4 hours ago but no use

**I think the problem here**

```
String x = response.getString("message");
```

I need help please

Comment: What error or output did you get?? also post that

Comment: does not get any error but does not fetch data but when I put an existing city name data is fetched I do not know why I just want to check Is the name of the city present or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting json text in the response body, but the server is responding with 404 code which is an error, therefore the logic needs to be inside the overridden method:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
   String body;
   String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
   if(statusCode == "400") {
       // do your thing
   }
   // do something else
```

}

Comment: Yes, I forgot the quotes... or you can remove them and also the String conversion in "String.valueOf..." and change the statusCode type to int.

Answer (score 0):

Json Might be look like

```
{"loginNodes":[{"message":"Welcome To Alamofire","name":Enamul Haque,"errorCode":"0","photo":null}]}
```

Your code should be ..

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //pDialog.dismiss();


                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("loginNodes");
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                         String message=  jo.getString("message");
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {

                    } catch (Exception e) {


                    }
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("q", "fddfgdfgdfgdfg");
            params.put("units", "metric");
            params.put("appid", "efb8013262db1b77b0431909b8b173e1");

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Check response from GET OR Post.You can debug the error onErrorResponse

```
try {

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError ) {

                        }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){

                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            //TODO
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            //TODO
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            //TODO
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
```